# Convert the number 1999 to the year 1999 - in date format in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

This has to be easy, and extremely common, but I can't find the answer with Google.

I have a column with years (number format) in Excel.  I need that column in Excel to be in date format for importing into Tableau. (There may be a way to fix this in Tableua - not relevant here.)

I see way to have a date only show the year in Excel ('yyy').

When I convert my number to a date, I get this:
1999 -> format cells (*3/4/2012) -> 06/21/1905
06/21/1905 -> format cells (yyyy) -> 1905
1999 -> format cells (yyyy) -> 1905

I want 1999 (convert to date format) -> 1999

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What day in 1999?  You can't just convert 1999 to a date in 1999 without additional information in Excel

Comment: if you format 1999 to date time it'll mean the 1999th day since the epoch ([00-Jan-1900 in Excel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28computing%29)). Try `([datetime]"1899-12-31").AddDays(1998)` in PowerShell and see how it prints exactly that date. You can't mix year-only and datetime data withing a single date format

Comment: `1999` isn't a date; it's *part* of a date. You have to pick a month and day, too. If Jan 1 is OK, then you can use this formula: `=DATE(A1,1,1)`. That will return a date value of Jan 1 in the year given as a number in `A1`.

Comment: @EngineerToast  Your comment works. The "1999" is not obliterated. That is a formula I can copy to cells to replace the date column with. It's better than the answer to my own question I posted - where I just manually typed in 1/1/x in all the rows.  Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1999` isn't a date; it's part of a date. You have to pick a month and day, too. If Jan 1 is OK, then you can use this formula: `=DATE(A1,1,1)`. That will return a date value of Jan 1 in the year given as a number in `A1`. You can also copy/paste this as needed so you have both the original data and the date value for an entire range of cells.

Comment: This eliminates the problem where coverting 1999 to a date clobbers 1999  -  and it's a formula I can copy across cells, rather than being a macro.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. type 1999-01-01 in e.g. cell `A1`, this will normally also format it as a date
2. type `=A1` in `A2` and set formatting to Number (using the dialog launched by CTRL-1) - this will tell the number that represents Jan 1 1999.
3. type a `0` in `B1`, set the format to Date or Time showing Date - it will tell what date a zero value represents.
   The number in A2 tells how many **days** A1 is from the base date (in B1) which is encoded as zero.

Assuming that B1 shows "1900" (or "1899-12-30 00:00", LibreOffice)...
Type 1999 in C1, type `=(C1-1900)*365.263` in C2. Format C2 as Date

Comment: I am aware that I can type 1/1/1999, 1/1/2000 and manually replace every year.  It's a lot easier than you describe. You just type in the full date, and then change the format to 'yyyy.'    ----   I'm looking for a way to do this without manually typing in all the data.

Comment: ... hence the formula; as an indication of how to do it. `=DATE(y,m,d)` is of course a better way.

Answer (score -1):

I just went through and did this manually.

I made a new column, set its format to date, and typed 1/1/1999 for the first row, 1/1/2000 for the second, etc.

Then I changed the format of the column to 'yyyy' so it just shows the year.

Now Tableau is working as expected with this Excel sheet.  (It does a "sum" on the year field, and there's only one data point per year, so the sum is the value I want in the line).

I will check back later to see if someone posted an answer that doesn't require the person to manually type in every date.  There probably a way to do this with a macro, but that's dirty IMO.